# Etymology of "gender"

Tags: meaning, etymology, sex-vs-gender

According to [OED](https://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/77468), the English word "gender" was originally a loan from Norman French, meaning **'kind/type'** e.g.

> Byshinynge & liȝt ben diuers as species and *gendir*; for eueryche bischinynge is liȝt, but not aȝenwarde.
>
> - 1398   J. Trevisa tr. Bartholomaeus Anglicus De Proprietatibus Rerum (BL Add. 27944) (1975) I. viii. xxix. 511

This was then used specifically to refer to the different **genders of nouns and pronouns** in languages (most commonly **masculine/feminine** as in Old English, as opposed to other divisions e.g. animacy).

> Hire name, þat was femynyn Of *gendre*, heo turned in to masculyn.
>
> - c1390 (?c1350) St. Theodora l. 110 in C. Horstmann Sammlung Altengl. Legenden (1878) 36 (MED)

> In the Indian languages, those discriminating words or inflections which we call *genders*, are not, as with us,..intended to distinguish between male and female beings, but between animate and inanimate things.
>
> - 1819   Trans. Hist. & Lit. Comm. Amer. Philos. Soc. 1 368

Hence (by analogy) the word became a highbrow synonym of **"sex"**:

> His heyres of the masculine *gender* of his body lawfully begoten.
>
> - 1474   in C. L. Kingsford Stonor Lett. & Papers (1919) I. 142 (MED)

At some point in the late 19th century the word ["sex"](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/176989) acquires a secondary meaning of "sexual intercourse" in vernacular, and in the 20th century the synonym "gender" increases in popularity to avoid vulgar connotations:

> We marry in fear and trembling, *sex* for a home is the woman's traffic, and the man comes to his heart's desire when his heart's desire is dead.
>
> - 1900   H. G. Wells Love & Mr. Lewisham xvii. 144

And then at some point later in the 20th century people start using "gender" in a [broader](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gender) sense to also refer to **psycho-social identity** independent of a given biological definition of sex:

> In the grade-school years, too, *gender* (which is the socialized obverse of sex) is a fixed line of demarkation, the qualifying terms being ‘feminine’ and ‘masculine’.
>
> - 1945   Amer. Jrnl. Psychol. 58 228

(possibly as an abbreviation of "gender role" / ["gender identity"](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/98220733)?):

> Imprinting and establishment of *gender role*.
>
> - 1957   Arch. Neurol. & Psychiat. 77 333 (heading)

> She has for many years been interested in the field of psychology, particularly in the areas of *gender identity* and personality expression.
>
> - 1964   Valley News (Van Nuys, Calif.) 29 Nov. 22/2

Later this is used in contrast to "sex" which retains the narrower biological meaning.

---

Is this understanding and timeline correct, and can someone provide me with the earliest recorded use/time periods the word "gender" underwent changes in meaning / acquired the new meanings above?

Comment: I think asking for a list of all the changes in meaning is too broad a question to be on-topic here. I don't know if others agree, but you might want to consider narrowing the scope down a bit.

Comment: The full subscription-only OED has **1382** as the first use of the verb ***to gender = to copulate***, but **1390** for the first use of the noun ***gender** = each of the classes (typically **masculine, feminine, neuter, common**) of nouns and pronouns distinguished by the different inflections which they have and which they require in words syntactically associated with them*. They also have a third separate entry for the verb in the sense *To assign or ... differentiate on the basis of gender.* Which I suspect *doesn't* fit well with OP's hoped-for history of the word/s.

Comment: ...they say that third sense was first recorded 1825, but it was ***rare** before mid 20th cent*.